# Why can't add constraints for the UIView created in storyboard?

Tags: autolayout, constraints

I try to add constraints for UIview which is IBOutlet property, but it seems not work. And I also    set TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to no.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.\

[_view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_view1);

[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_view1(40)]-30-|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_view1(30)]"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:views]];

}
```

Anything should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the view constraints, before other constraints, if this view have any constraints in storyboard...

Comment: I haven't add constraints on the storyboard, to ensure that I have clear constraints on storyboard. It does't work.